# How to use preInstalled map in offline address search in skmaps in android

Tags: android, maps, skmaps

Hello i want to use the pre install maps for offline searching so that the user of the application will not need to download the country offline map. can somebody tell me how to use it on offline search in android? thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose you are referring to distribute the map as a prebundled app?!

Comment: If you are looking for geocoding (offline search) that is only possible on an offline map. If you want to perform POI search (nearby search) that is possible also online

Comment: Can i search geocoding/POI via name of the place not the geo location?

Answer (score 3):

For distributing the map as a prebundled app you need to follow the next steps:

- start the demo project (with internet connection on) - go the Map XML & download menu, choose a country/city and download it
- On the device you should be able to find the downloaded package (in my case it was at /Volumes/NO NAME/Android/data/com.skobbler.sdkdemo/files/SKMaps/Maps/v1/20140320/package ) (you can search for .skm files to make things easier)
  [cid:3F0D177D-2E09-42A3-AE03-C52ECC682CA7]
- Take the 3 files and drop them in the SkMaps.zip file in the PreinstalledMaps/v1/20140320/meta/package (the 20140320 depends on which SDK version you are using) (you will need to unpack and repack the zip file)
  [cid:AC4686BE-9672-4D5D-B3B4-EAD9DA9C42F4]
- In SplashActivity.java make sure you uncomment the 3 lines responsible for prebundled maps

// EXAMPLE OF ADDING PREINSTALLED MAPS

```
     initMapSettings.setPreinstalledMapsPath(app.getMapResourcesDirPath()

     + "/PreinstalledMaps");

     initMapSettings.setConnectivityMode(SKMaps.CONNECTIVITY_MODE_OFFLINE);
```

- Run again the demo, with the phone in offline mode (just to make sure that there's no internet connection)

On some devices it might not work with a very big prebundled map (e.g. Switzerland has ~ 90 MB) so you should check first with a smaller map – e.g. Andorra

Comment: thanks for the answer. but i already did that. how to use it on offline search address? and you said that i gonna put the 3 files on "PreinstalledMaps/v1/20140320/meta/package" I put it on "PreinstalledMaps/v1/20140320/package". do i need to put it on meta folder? because meta folder don't have package folder.

Comment: Edgar-it's ok the way you've done. You don't need to put it in the meta folder.